# LinkedList (built from scratch) add() not working

Tags: java, linked-list, addition, doubly-linked-list

I'm working on a class assignment where I must build a singly linkedlist class from scratch. My problem here is that my add() method isn't quite working when I iterate through a series of items and add them to a linkedlist. More specifically, 1) it is duplicating the first one in a series, and 2) it is not adding the last one in a series. What is wrong with my add() method in the ManualLinkedList class?

```
public class test {
    static class ManualLinkedList<T> {
        private static class Node<T> {
            T item;
            Node<T> next;
            Node<T> prev;

            public T getItem() {
                    return item;
                }
            public ManualLinkedList.Node<T> getNext() {
                    return next;
                }

            Node(Node<T> prev, T element, Node<T> next) {
                this.item = element;
                this.next = next;
                this.prev = prev;
            }
        }

        Node<T> head;
        Node<T> tail;
        int size = 0;

        public void add(T t) {
            final Node<T> l = tail;
            final Node<T> newNode = new Node<>(l, t, null);
            tail = newNode;
            if (l == null) {
                head = newNode;
            }
            else {
                l.next = newNode;
            }
            size++;
        }

        public int size() { return size; }

        public T getContentFromPosition(int position) {
            Node<T> np = head;
            T result = head.getItem();

            if (position == size) {
                result = tail.getItem();
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
                if (i == position) {
                    result = np.getItem();
                }
                np = np.getNext();
            }
            return result;
        }
    } //end ManualLinkedList class


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ManualLinkedList<Integer> test = new ManualLinkedList<>();
        test.add(1);
        test.add(2);
        test.add(3);
        test.add(4);
        test.add(5);
        test.add(6);
        test.add(7);
        test.add(8);

        for (int i =0; i < test.size; i++){
            System.out.println(test.getContentFromPosition(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Actual Output:

```
1
1  // notice the duplicate first item
2
3
4
5
6
7  // notice the missing 8, or the last input
```

Comment: Note that the singly-linked list nodes have only one ptr that points to the next element. It does not contain ptr to prev entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Primary Issues

1. index is used as `0..size-1` during invocation
2. `for` loop in `getContentFromPosition` should be from `0..size-1`
3. The usage of size == position is irrelevant in `getContentFromPosition`

### Code

```java
        public T getContentFromPosition(int position) {
            if (position >= size) {
                return null;
            }
            Node<T> np = head;
            T result = head.getItem();
            if (position == size - 1) {
                result = tail.getItem();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (i == position) {
                    result = np.getItem();
                    break;
                }
                np = np.next;
            }
            return result;
        }
    } //end ManualLinkedList class


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ManualLinkedList<Integer> test = new ManualLinkedList<>();
        test.add(1);
        test.add(2);
        test.add(3);
        test.add(4);
        test.add(5);
        test.add(6);
        test.add(7);
        test.add(8);

        for (int i = 0; i < test.size; i++){
            System.out.println(test.getContentFromPosition(i));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `add` function is actually fine.

However, your `getContentFromPosition` function is almost right, but needs a little work.  You should decide whether the positions in your list count from 0 or from 1.  For example, if there are 3 elements in a list, are they are positions 0, 1, 2 or positions 1, 2, 3?

When you are using the `getContentFromPosition` function from main, you are assuming that positions count from 0, but in writing the function, it looks like you were assuming that they count from 1.

If you modify the `getContentFromPosition` to count from 0, then you can get rid of the special case checking for position==size, and you would then start the loop at 0, not 1.  Also, for efficiency, why not return the result when you find it rather than let the loop continue to run?

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialized `int size=1` instead of `0`

and in the main method for loop change to  `int i=1` instead of `0`

Answer (score 0):

in getContentFromPosition method, your for loop should start from 0. Rest is fine.

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)